# Can dedicated instances share same hardware within the same account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dedicated

I was going through AWS docs for [Dedicated Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/dedicated-instance.html) and I'm confused by the following statement:

*Dedicated Instances might share hardware with other instances from the same AWS account that are not Dedicated Instances.*

(I'm assuming *hardware* here means a physical server)

It explains about sharing the hardware with other non-dedicated instances, but what about sharing the hardware with other dedicated instances within same the account?

Can a hardware be shared by two dedicated instances within the same account?

If not then, wouldn't that be expensive to allocate separate hardware for each dedicated instance request?

Answer (score 2):

yes - sharing hardware across your dedicated instances is its main purpose:

> Dedicated Instances ... run ... on hardware that's dedicated to a single customer.

In other words, other customers' instances don't run on the same hardware as your dedicated instances.

Reference that you quote is clarification that AWS *may* run **your** non-dedicated instances on the same hardware **as well**

Comment: I had the same confusion as OP and I feel that they should have said exactly that, `AWS may run your non-dedicated instance on the same hardware as well` and you should get credit for that.